# C++ Reads/Writes XML without CLR

Tags: xml, visual-c++, dll, native-code

I know this is a very stupid question and I'm very new to C++.

I'm developing Starcraft AI, it is DLL file. I'm trying to use XML to gather some data to the bot, however whenever I build the DLL with /clr option. The bot doesn't load properly. So, my question is what is CLR and is there a way to read/write XML without using /clr build option.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not going to help you program a bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/clr` flag means that you're building it as a C++/CLI app which means that it'll be managed code (using the the .Net framework etc). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) for more information.

You probably want to do native code so I'd suggest that you use something like MSXml or [Xerces XML library](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) to read the XML and make sure that you don't use any .Net classes. There's probably other XML libraries, but those are the only two I've used from C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Microsoft's solution and you are familiar with COM interfaces, you can try [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753804.aspx). As an easy to use open-source alternative I'd recommend [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) (I use it in some of my Windows apps and find it satisfying).